# Angular tests - NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NgxPermissionsDirective -> NgxPermissionsService]

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am testing a component that uses ngx-permissions but I get the error - NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NgxPermissionsDirective -> NgxPermissionsService]... yet I have imported the module.
My test bed is configured as shown below:

```js
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ApplicationDetailsComponent],
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        PipeModule,
        MaterialModule,
        NgxLoadingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ToasterTestingModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgxPermissionsModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useClass: MockAuthService,
        },
        {
          provide: AnotherService,
          useClass: AnotherServiceMock,
        },
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {...route},
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
```

Comment: have you tried with `NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import {
  NgxPermissionsAllowStubDirective,
  NgxPermissionsModule,
} from 'ngx-permissions';

describe('TestComponentA', () => {
  let component: ComponentA;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentA>;
  let service: ComponentAService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
      ],
      declarations: [ComponentA, NgxPermissionsAllowStubDirective],
      providers: [],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

})
```

Comment: I just added it to my SharedTestingModule